# Missing $ using Align and Tabular

Tags: tables, align

I'm needing some help to fix this minor error, can't seem to find where's the missing $ character.

I've tried to add $$ for both \mathbb{P} and \mathbb{Q}. Latex compiled and showed it in plaintext instead.

Appreciate your kind help. Thanks.

```
\begin{align}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\text{P} =\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P} & ,\mathbb{P}_{length} > \mathbb{Q}_{length} \\
\mathbb{Q} & ,\mathbb{Q}_{length} > \mathbb{P}_{length}
\end{cases}   \hspace{2em}  &  \hspace{2em}
\text{Q} =\begin{cases}
\mathbb{Q} & ,\mathbb{P}_{length} > \mathbb{Q}_{length} \\
\mathbb{P} & ,\mathbb{Q}_{length} > \mathbb{P}_{length}
\end{cases}
\end{tabular}
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tabular` is normally for text, not math.  If you want math, then you could try the `array` environment.  But the point of `align` is that you don't need the `array` environment.  Could you just leave that out?  And since you're not using any lines within `array` (the only `\\` you have is in `cases`), you could change `align` to `equation` (and drop the `&` that isn't in `cases`).  You should also use `\mathrm` with the "length"s (and probably nothing for `P` and `Q`, although that would depend on what they're doing).  That would leave you with:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
P =\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P} & ,\mathbb{P}_{\mathrm{length}} > \mathbb{Q}_{\mathrm{length}} \\
\mathbb{Q} & ,\mathbb{Q}_{\mathrm{length}} > \mathbb{P}_{\mathrm{length}}
\end{cases}   \hspace{4em}
Q =\begin{cases}
\mathbb{Q} & ,\mathbb{P}_{\mathrm{length}} > \mathbb{Q}_{\mathrm{length}} \\
\mathbb{P} & ,\mathbb{Q}_{\mathrm{length}} > \mathbb{P}_{\mathrm{length}}
\end{cases}
\end{document}
```

There was some discussion about difference between `\mathrm` and `\text`.  You could look at something like `\emph{A distance like $P_{\mathrm{length}}$ is always positive.}`  With `\text`, the subscript would be italic, unlike other occurrences of the variable.

And depending on the relation of `\mathbb{P}` and `\mathbb{P}_{\mathrm{length}}`, you might be able to simply say `P=\max(\mathbb{P}_{\mathrm{length}},\mathbb{Q}_{\mathrm{length}})` and `\min` for `Q`.

Comment: Hi Teepeemm, 

thanks for the advice... i removed the tabular and it compiled fine now..
i wanted to use tabular to place the equations side by side.. but i didnt know i could do it using align by itself..

Comment: Note that `\text` is not the right command: it should most likely be `\mathrm`

Comment: @ClarenceCheong For side by side, you don't really need anything.  The point of `align`, `tabular`, `array`, `cases`, etc., is to have separate lines line up the same way.  That's way things line up correctly in the `cases` environment.  But since `cases` takes care of its thing, you don't need it for the rest of your expression.

Comment: @Teepeemm `\text` uses the font that was current when the formula started, `\mathrm` will use upshape in every case.

Comment: thanks for the advice @egreg, i've updated the `\text` to `\mathrm` but i dont see any difference. 

@Teepeemm, noted regarding the `align` and `cases` ... will try to remove the `align` and make it work only with `cases`

Comment: @ClarenceCheong Try using `\text{P}` in a theorem statement.